# Is there a issue in my loop between parsing a character to ascii to comparing the assigned value i already set?

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, ascii

I have a program that takes info from a text file then tells the user how many of the specific alphabets,commas,spaces and periods used. However when out putting it only shows 0 for everything.My text file has text in it and I suspect it maybe something with my loop but I am not sure.

```
    //read from a file
    BufferedReader readFile= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("mytext.txt"));
    //Counts record
    while ((strInput=readFile.readLine())!=null)
    {
         intRecCount++;
    }

    character=new char[intRecCount];
    strRecord=new String[intRecCount];



    //open file
    readFile=new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("mytext.txt"));



    //input info
    for (int i=0;i<strRecord.length;i++)
    {
       strRecord[i]=readFile.readLine();
    }

    //input valyes one by one per record
    for (int i=0; i<strRecord.length;i++)
    {
        character[i]=strRecord[i].charAt(i);
        intCompare=(int)character[i];

        //for letters
        for (int x=0;x<=25;x++)
        {
            if (intCompare==intUpLetter[x])
            {
                intCounter[x]++;

            }

            if (intCompare==intLowLetter[x])
            {
                intCounter[x]++;

            }

        }
        // for the the 3 punction marks
        for (int y=0;y<=2;y++)
        {
            if (intCompare==intPunct[y])
            {
                intCounter[25+y]++;

            }


        }

       System.out.println("You have this many"+intCounter[0]+" A's");
       System.out.println("You have this many"+intCounter[1]+" B's");
       System.out.println("You have this many"+intCounter[2]+" C's");
       System.out.println("You have this many"+intCounter[3]+" D's");
       System.out.println("You have this many"+intCounter[4]+" E's");
       System.out.println("You have this many"+intCounter[5]+" F's");
       System.out.println("You have this many"+intCounter[6]+" G's");
       System.out.println("You have this many"+intCounter[7]+" H's");
       System.out.println("You have this many"+intCounter[8]+" I's");
       System.out.println("You have this many"+intCounter[9]+" J's");
       System.out.println("You have this many"+intCounter[10]+" K's");
       System.out.println("You have this many"+intCounter[11]+" L's");
       System.out.println("You have this many"+intCounter[12]+" M's");
       System.out.println("You have this many"+intCounter[13]+" N's");
       System.out.println("You have this many"+intCounter[14]+" O's");
       System.out.println("You have this many"+intCounter[15]+" P's");
       System.out.println("You have this many"+intCounter[16]+" Q's");
       System.out.println("You have this many"+intCounter[17]+" R's");
       System.out.println("You have this many"+intCounter[18]+" S's");
       System.out.println("You have this many"+intCounter[19]+" T's");
       System.out.println("You have this many"+intCounter[20]+" U's");
       System.out.println("You have this many"+intCounter[21]+" V's");
       System.out.println("You have this many"+intCounter[22]+" W's");
       System.out.println("You have this many"+intCounter[23]+" X's");
       System.out.println("You have this many"+intCounter[24]+" Y's");
       System.out.println("You have this many"+intCounter[25]+" Z's");
       System.out.println("You have this many"+intCounter[26]+" space's");
       System.out.println("You have this many"+intCounter[27]+" comma's");
       System.out.println("You have this many"+intCounter[28]+" periods'");
    }
```

No error messages but the output should be 3 for each alphabet and punctuation mark listed.However 0 appears for all.

Comment: A to int value is not 1. I'd recommend going through an exercise of outputting the int value of the letters to properly cast.

Comment: where do initialize intUpLetter intLowLetter .... ?

Answer (score 0):

You are only looking at the i'th character of the i'th line of text.  You need two loops, one looping over lines (which you have) and one looping over the characters in each line (which you lack).

Original:

```
//input info
for (int i=0;i<strRecord.length;i++)
{
   strRecord[i]=readFile.readLine();
}

//input valyes one by one per record
for (int i=0; i<strRecord.length;i++)
{
    character[i]=strRecord[i].charAt(i);
    intCompare=(int)character[i];
        :
 }
```

You need something like

```
for (int i=0; i<strRecord.length;i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<strRecord[i].length; j++) {
         … deal with strRecord[i].charAt(j); …
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your expertise, It really helped out alot :)